# AM-GM-HM inequality problem

Tags: inequality, means, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Prove that  $a^5 + b^5 +c^5 >abc (ab+bc+ac) $ for all positive distinct values of a, b & c.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$a^5+b^5+c^5+a^5+b^5>5abcab$

$a^5+b^5+c^5+b^5+c^5>5abcbc$

$a^5+b^5+c^5+a^5+c^5>5abcac$

Strict inequalities hold since $a$, $b$ and $c$ are distinct.

Add them up and the result follows.